# php how to remove leading zeros from a CSV?

Tags: php

Ok, let's say I have a string that is CSV: 01,02,05,10,11,13.. what would be the easiest way to remove the leading zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` for this:

```
$text = "01,02,05,10,11,13,101"; 
echo preg_replace('/(?<=,|\b)0([0-9])/', "$1", $text);
```

**EDIT:** Updated the regex to work with numbers with a `0` in the middle of them. (i.e. 101)
Thanks to **@BoltClock** for helping fix the regex.

Output:

```
1,2,5,10,11,13,101
```

The advantage to doing it this way is you don't have to mess with turning all the text into an array, modifying it/looping through it, and then turning it back into text.

Comment: I was considering posting this solution too. It's cleaner and more obvious of its intent. But they both work fine if his list always looks like that (no spaces or non-decimal numbers).

Comment: What if one of the numbers is `101`? It will make it `11`.

Comment: Ah, well for the application I am using it won't go above 30 or so anyway, but good point.

Comment: @BoltClock's solution is much more elegant then mine. I'd opt to use his. Also, @BoltClock, that regex doesn't work; It throws PHP errors. I was trying to figure out a working version, but it's not worth it. He really should use the `array_map` solution.

Comment: @webbiedave, @Michael Irigoyen: I keep messing up my positive lookbehinds. It should have been `/(?<=,)0([0-9])/`

Comment: Almost! It works, except on the first value. The results are `01,2,5,10,11,13,101`.

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen: In that case we'll just work with OP's assumption :)

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen: Yeah I found `/(?<=,|^)0([0-9])/` works too.

Answer (score 10):

If they are all integers, explode it into an array and convert all to ints.

```
$values = array_map('intval', explode(',', $csv));
```

Comment: Same as mine but condensed. I like it.

Comment: This is an excellent method for turning them into an int. Thanks BoltClock

Comment: @John: Yup except if you wanted back a string you'd have to `implode()` the array again.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, that's the only reason I accepted Michael's answer above yours, it keeps it as a string which is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>A bit lo-fi, but using [ltrim](http://www.php.net/ltrim) should do the trick:</strike>

```
$zeroLess = ltrim('01', '0');
```

Alternatively (and substantially more correctly), use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) as follows:

```
$zeroLess = intval('01');
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I thought the single leading zero would indicate octal notation, causing `intval()` to mess up. But it looks like I was a little paranoid! `ltrim()` works too, however, so I upvoted you.

Comment: ltrim works if it's a single number, but not in a CSV.. I would have to run it for each value in the CSV wouldn't I?

Comment: @John Take a look at @BoltClock's answer - it uses the intval function as a callback to array_map and solves the problem very neatly.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast all your numbers to ints:

```
$list = explode(',', $csv_string);
foreach ($list as &$n) $n = (int)$n;
$fixed = implode(',', $list);
```

Make sure to note that `&` in the foreach, which lets you modify the actual list elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$tdata=explode(',','01,02,05,10,11,13');
foreach ($tdata as $number) {
    $csv[]=number_format($number,0);
}
$csv=implode(',',$csv);
echo $csv;
```

tested: http://www.ideone.com/lrh8q

**edit**

Looking at some of the other posts, casting to int instead of number_format is probably faster.